# How to store model data in Userdefaults swift?

Tags: swift, class, nsuserdefaults, swift5

My model class:

```
struct AllRestroVendor:Codable{
let vendorID, name: String?
let rating: Rating?
let option: [Options]?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case vendorID = "vendor_id"
    case name
    case rating
    case options
}}

struct Rating: Codable {
let count, rating, image, name: String?
}

struct Options: Codable{
let name, price: String?
}
```

I am trying to store this model data in userdefaults.

```
func setWishList(details :AllRestroVendor) {

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(details) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(encoded, forKey: UD_WISHLIST)
    }
    userdefaultsSynchronize()
}

func getWishList() -> AllRestroVendor {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if let topicsList = defaults.object(forKey: "topic_list") as? Data {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let loadedList = try? decoder.decode(AllRestroVendor.self, from: topicsList) {
            return loadedList
        }
    }

    let aData = AllRestroVendor(vendorID: "", name: "", rating: Rating?, options: [])
    return aData
}
```

Here getting an error "Cannot convert value of type 'Rating?.Type' to expected argument type 'Rating?'"

I gothrough every anyswers. But unfortunately cannot resolve this issue. Help me to solve this.

Comment: In the line `let aData = AllRestroVendor(vendorID: "", name: "", rating: Rating?, options: [])` you need to pass an actual instance of a `Rating`. Passing `Rating?` is like trying to pass `String?` to the `name` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. for vendorId and options I have passed empty string and array. should i pass empty dictionary here?

Comment: To make it compile you need to pass values for all attributes but why not return nil of the decoding fails?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson in some point it may crash my app. So i am returning empty values

Comment: It will not crash if you learn to handle nil values, I mean you already have properties in your custom type that can be nil so you are already facing that problem. If you insist on returning an object then use an init for Ranking that takes all properties as arguments in the same way you already do for AllRestroVendor.

Comment: return empty value of Rating by making an empty instance `Rating(count: "", rating: "", image: "", name: "")` instead of `Rating?`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for your help. It helped me to understand the problem.